# How to select Scene (UIStoryBoard) depending on user?

Tags: ios, ios5, uistoryboard

I am using Storyboards.
Basically my app is about

On first launch 
-You get a naviguation controller + view controller (let's call it View A) 
-You are asked to log in 

On other launch 
-You still get a nav controller but
-If you are logged, I want to get immediately to a new view (let's call it View B)
-If you are not logged, I want to show back View A

How do I do this
if(logged in) show View B
else if(not logged in) show View A

With .xib, this isn't too difficult, but with Storyboards, I really don't know how to get this working ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's something that you can do , i am not sure if it is the best way but, you could make viewB as your main view and with your opening just create a segue from B->A initially. this will give you the opportunity to control 2 of your views, then check if the user has logged in or not , if the user has already logged in just pop the viewA if not let the user login and then pop.

or you can go with a different approach , you can create another view which is lets say viewC and create 2 segues from this view to the other 2 to control the view load operations.

hope this helps ..

Comment: Thank you ! It helped ! So basically, I did a segue from A->B and I called [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegueId" sender: self];